# How to fix error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I am encountering and I was wondering how I can fix it. I'm new to rails and I didn't think that .each was a method. If some one could please help me it would be very apreciated. thanks

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

this is the code that i am getting the error on.

```
<h1>Portfolio Items</h1>

<% @portfolio_items.each do |portfolio_item| %>
  <p><%= portfolio_item.title %></p>
  <p><%= portfolio_item.subtitle %></p>
  <p><%= portfolio_item.body %></p>
  <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where do you define `@portfolio_items`?

Comment: `@portfolio_items` has no value (i.e. is `nil`), share your controller to help you spot the error.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Either you have not set the var `@portfolio_items` or its mis-spelled. 
If you have defined it then at least it should have had `Array` like data structure And prevented this error.

Some of the array like objects will be `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`

> In ruby undefined @instance vars are set with `nil` and no error is raised.

If this does not help, please update your question with more details and I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
[nil].each{|e| p e}
=> nil
```

You can see there's an element inside the array, so you can use `each`, you can iterate and print its content, and you'll see there's a `nil` value inside.

If in the other hand you write:

```
nil.each{|e| p e}
```

You'll get the error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

That's to say there's no `each` method available between all the methods that can be applied to `nil`.

In your code, in the controller most probably, you're defining `@portfolio_items`, but for some reason, this isn't taking the value you want, it's getting a `nil` value, so when you try to iterate over it, you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

You code is expecting @portfolio_items to be an array, but  either @portfolio_items is not assigned a value or assigned a nil in the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

your list is `nil`, you can do an `if...else` check to handle it on your view template

```
<h1>Portfolio Items</h1>

<% if @portfolio_items.count == 0 %>
  <p>There are no items</p>
<% else %>
  <% @portfolio_items.each do |portfolio_item| %>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.title %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.subtitle %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.body %></p>
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use :

```
(@portfolio_items || []).each do |portfolio_item|
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable `@portfolio_items` is nil and `each` loop over `nil` is throw error.

So follow below code:

```
<h1>Portfolio Items</h1>

<% if @portfolio_items.nil? %>
  No Item to display.
<% else %>
  <% @portfolio_items.each do |portfolio_item| %>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.title %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.subtitle %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.body %></p>
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless   portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```